# How to use Tailwind CSS with Jekyll?

Tags: tailwind-css, jekyll

I'm trying to use Tailwind CSS to make my current Jekyll site responsive. I followed this article: https://medium.com/on-web-development/use-jekyll-and-tailwind-css-354ea2320e92

When I added the following code to my `main.css` file

```
---
---
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

I received the following error: `{ expectedcss(css-lcurlyexpected)`

I'm a complete beginning and couldn't figure out how to resolve this issue.

I tried simply removing the dashes at the beginning but it seems like Jekyll needs the main css file to be YAML front matter.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not using SASS, you may not need the top two lines of dashes. Those are for Jekyll to process the file. Since you are using Tailwind to process it, you should not need those.

I just started a new Jekyll site and my main.css looks like:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body {
  @apply bg-gray-100;
}
```

Also, that post is showing what may be an older way of setting up tailwind. Try https://www.syntaxjournal.com/how-to-add-tailwindcss-jekyll/ which I just used wit success.

I also have it where I can run both Jekyll and Tailwind from the same command:

```
  "scripts": {
    "jekyll": "bundle exec jekyll serve",
    "tailwind": "tailwindcss -i ./assets/main.css -o ./assets/styles.css --watch",
    "start": "TAILWIND_MODE=watch NODE_ENV=development npm-run-all --parallel jekyll tailwind"
  },
```

Hope this helps.